# Making 2 types of thumbnails using tinyMCE imagemanager plugin

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Inside iimagemanager config file there is option to make thumbnail of specific width and height.

But what if I want 2 different types of thumbnails. There is no such option in config.

Is there any way to do 2 types ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out this page: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/MCImageManager:upload.format

here's what I've used in my config file to create 2 extra thumbs (in addition to the one created by create_thumbnail)

```
//extra thumbnail creation
$mcImageManagerConfig['upload.format'] = '600x600=thumbs600/%f.%e,200x200=thumbs200/%f.%e'; //creates a 610x610 in thumbs610/ and 225x225 in thumbs225/
/* upload.format options:
    %f -> Filename without extension for example "myimage". 
    %e -> Extension the extension part of the image for example "gif". 
    %w -> Output image width, the proportional value. 
    %h -> Output image height, the proportional valie. 
    %tw -> Target width/specified width by the resize option. 
    %th -> Target height/specified height by the resize option. 
    %ow -> Original width, before the image gets resized. 
    %oh -> Original height, before the image gets resize. */
```